# How to move all lines with the first 10 characters that are identical to a common column?

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

I have a file that has one column that looks like this:

```
chr1 106623419
chr1 106623434
chr1 106623436
chr1 110611528
chr1 110611536
chr1 110611550
chr1 110611552
chr1 111216608
chr1 111216621
chr1 111216624
chr1 111216627
chr1 111216628
```

I want to sort so I am selecting all the lines that share the same first 10 characters and put them in their own column like this

```
chr1 106623419  chr1 110611528  chr1 111216608
chr1 106623434  chr1 110611536  chr1 111216621
chr1 106623436  chr1 110611550  chr1 111216624
                chr1 110611552  chr1 111216627
                                chr1 111216628
```

Comment: did you try anything yourself?

Comment: I have used grep to search the file for the first 10 characters individually for a smaller file. I don't know how to search multiple at once and output it into separate columns of an output file. I'm still new to this.

Comment: do you specifically need solution written in bash?

Comment: I have actually figured it out another way using a second file to search the first. Thank you though.

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:

```
perl -ne 'chomp;
          push @{ $h{ substr $_, 0, 10 } }, substr $_, 10;
          }{
          while (grep @$_, values %h) {
              for my $p (keys %h) {
                  $s = shift @{ $h{$p} };
                  print $s ? "$p$s" : "\t", "\t";
              }
              print "\n";
          }' input.file
```

How it works: it creates a hash map of prefix -> array of suffixes. Once the input is over (`}{`), it shifts values from those arrays one by one and prints them to columns. If no value remains in an array, tab is printed instead.

Comment: I'm not super familiar or knowledgeable when it comes to perl, how would I export the output to a file?

Comment: @Batwood: Your question is not related to perl. Use standard shell redirection: `... > output`

Comment: I appreciate the script but I ultimately want to put the output in an excel spreadsheet and the output for this perl script does not formate well in excel. The columns don't seem to line up.

Comment: @Batwood: So remove the first tab and leave it empty `: "", "\t"`, or separate the columns with semicolons or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution in `gawk` version 4

```
gawk 'BEGIN{max=0; OFS="\t"}
{
    key = int($2/1000000);
    d[key][length(d[key])+1] = $0;
    if(length(d[key])>max) 
        max = length(d[key]);
}
END{
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc";
    for(i=1; i<=max; ++i){ 
        line = "";
        flag = 0;
        for(j in d){
            line = line (flag?OFS:"") d[j][i];
            flag = 1;
        } 
        print line;
    }
}' file
```

you get:

```
chr1 106623419\tchr1 110611528\tchr1 111216608
chr1 106623434\tchr1 110611536\tchr1 111216621
chr1 106623436\tchr1 110611550\tchr1 111216624
\tchr1 110611552\tchr1 111216627
\t\tchr1 111216628
```

in other words:

```
chr1 106623419  chr1 110611528  chr1 111216608
chr1 106623434  chr1 110611536  chr1 111216621
chr1 106623436  chr1 110611550  chr1 111216624
                chr1 110611552  chr1 111216627
                                chr1 111216628
```

**Bonus**

Just for fun: online-`python`

```
from itertools import izip_longest, groupby
from string import strip
input = "file"

print("\n".join("\t".join(grp) for grp in izip_longest(*[map(strip, v) for k, v in groupby(open(input), key=lambda x: int(int(x.strip().split()[-1])/1000000))], fillvalue="")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, ruby:

```
ruby -e '
  groups = File.readlines(ARGV.shift)
               .map(&:chomp)
               .group_by {|item| item[0..9]}
               .values
               .sort
  max = groups.map(&:size).max
  # to transpose, the lists must all be the same length
  groups.collect {|list| list.fill("", list.length, max - list.length)}
        .transpose
        .each {|list| puts "%14s  %14s  %14s" % list}
' file
```